# Generate two pages of diagrams in iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

How I can create a report with two pages in the first bar chart and a crossTab in the second, the pages should have the header and footer.

I could not use the same band detail, so that the graph is duplicated.

Please an idea.

Comment: We need to see some code + what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gazillion of ways you can do this:

- Pass in data as parameters and create multiple detail bands (right click on detail, add another ...). Place whatever you want in the bands. You can create as many completely distinct pages as you like this way.
- Place an image in the detail band, and pass an image for each record (generate the graphs as images)
- Create two completely unrelated reports and print one after another, you can even combine them into a single print job, so the user doesn't even see that they are separate things.

Comment: when I add a new detail band, the graphics are duplicated according to the result of the sql, as I keep the picture is not duplicated?

Comment: Adding CrossTab in the detail band issued me this error. Error incrementing crosstab dataset

Answer (score 0):

well I managed to generate reports using $V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 in PrintWhenExpression, adding crosstab in band Sumary and allowing the header and footer is displayed in band Sumary.